# What get me this error?

Tags: java, exception

This is the poker game from my school project. I have some exception that I cannot figure out.

At the beginning, I defined the Card class.

```
class Card {

/* constant suits and ranks */
static final String[] Suit = {"Clubs", "Diamonds", "Hearts", "Spades" };
static final String[] Rank = {"","A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K"};

/* Data field of a card: rank and suit */
private int cardRank;  /* values: 1-13 (see Rank[] above) */
private int cardSuit;  /* values: 0-3  (see Suit[] above) */

/* Constructor to create a card */
/* throw MyPlayingCardException if rank or suit is invalid */
public Card(int rank, int suit) throws MyPlayingCardException { 
if ((rank < 1) || (rank > 13))
    throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid rank:"+rank);
else
        cardRank = rank;
if ((suit < 0) || (suit > 3))
    throw new MyPlayingCardException("Invalid suit:"+suit);
else
        cardSuit = suit;
}

/* Accessor and toString */
/* You may impelemnt equals(), but it will not be used */
public int getRank() { return cardRank; }
public int getSuit() { return cardSuit; }
public String toString() { return Rank[cardRank] + " " + Suit[cardSuit]; }


/* Few quick tests here */
public static void main(String args[])
{
try {
    Card c1 = new Card(1,3);    // A Spades
    System.out.println(c1);
    c1 = new Card(10,0);    // 10 Clubs
    System.out.println(c1);
    c1 = new Card(10,5);        // generate exception here
}
catch (MyPlayingCardException e)
{
    System.out.println("MyPlayingCardException: "+e.getMessage());
}
}
```

}

I created the Exception in this class. Then, in my Decks class, I keep on getting exception errors from the Deck constructor.

```
class Decks {

/* this is used to keep track of original n*52 cards */
private List<Card> originalDecks;   

/* this starts with n*52 cards deck from original deck   */
/* it is used to keep track of remaining cards to deal */
/* see reset(): it resets dealDecks to a full deck      */
private List<Card> dealDecks;

/* number of decks in this object */
private int numberDecks;


/**
 * Constructor: Creates default one deck of 52 playing cards in originalDecks and
 *          copy them to dealDecks.
 *              initialize numberDecks=n
 * Note: You need to catch MyPlayingCardException from Card constructor
 *       Use ArrayList for both originalDecks & dealDecks
 */
public Decks()
{
    // implement this method!

    ArrayList<Card> originalDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52);
    ArrayList<Card> dealDecks = new ArrayList<Card>(52); 

    for (int i=0; i<=3; i++)  {

        for (int j=0; j<= 13; j++)  {

                Card card = new Card(j,i);  
                originalDecks.add(card); 
            }               
        }

    dealDecks.addAll(originalDecks); 


}
```

Why is it? If I use my instance card is from the for loop (which means they i<3, j<13), why do I still get the Exception error?

```
unreported exception MyPlayingCardException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
                Card card = new Card(j,i);
```

Answer (score 3):

In java, you have to deal with the exceptions that your code *might* throw. This compiler error is saying that your `Card` constructor can throw an exception of type `MyPlayingCardException` but that your `Deck` constructor is doing nothing to handle it. There are two approaches here. You can either change your `Decks` constructor to read

```
public Decks() throws MyPlayingCardException
{
    //constructor code here
}
```

or you can handle the exception like this

```
for (int j=0; j<= 13; j++)  {

            try
            {
            Card card = new Card(j,i);  
            originalDecks.add(card); 
            }
            catch(MyPlayingCardException ex){
                //some code to handle MyPlayingCardException here
            }
        }               
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In java, an exception that is declared by a method or interface MUST be dealt with, either by catching it or passing it on to the next level.  In your code, the `Card()` constructor throws the exception.  Your `Decks()` constructor creates cards, but does not catch or throw the card exception.

Comment: Paul, are you saying if I throw the exception in Card(), it doesn't go to the memory and I have to throw/catch it again in the following Class?

Comment: You have to catch and throw anywhere along the call path where it might happen (unless it's a RuntimeException).

Comment: I substitute the line Card card = new Card(j,i) into the try...catch, like this: try{ Card card = new Card(j,i); }catchcatch (MyPlayingCardException e){ System.out.println("MyPlayingCardException: "+e.getMessage());}, but then it gives me error on the line behind it. What mistake I made here?